# dynamic subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: dynamic, subdomain

After reading posts here i was able to create dynamic subdomains with .htaccess file

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.sitename.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).sitename.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sitepath/subdomain.php?str1=%1

for this i had created one subdomain.php file with one variable i.e., str1 (name of the subdomain). Now what to achieve following results

1. subdomain.sitename.com  (this is done)
2. subdomain.sitename.com/str2/ (pass second variable in the query string)
3. subdomian.sitename.com/str2/str3/ (second and third variable)
4. if anybody add one more variable in the address bar manually should be redirected to 404 error page (subdomain.sitename.com/str2/str3/str4/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your RewriteConds lines only apply to one specific vhost in the first place.